# How can I input only integer and this integer will be only ending with zero?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, try-catch

I am trying to validate input values to pass only integers that are divisible by 10.  The code below is failing.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> liste = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // I have filled my array with integers
   int x=scan.nextInt();
int y=x%10;
do{
if(y==0){
liste.add(x);}
else if(y!=0){
System.out.println("It is not valid"); continue;
} 
else 
{System.out.println("Enter only integer"); continue;
}

}while(scan.hasNextInt()); }

        System.out.println(liste);
        System.out.println("Your largest value of your arraylist is: "+max(liste));
```

Comment: `enter code herepublic static void main(String args[]){` is an invalid method signature ;)

Comment: why don't you store the result of `scan.nextInt()` in a variable instead of calling it twice?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `scan.nextInt()` twice. Each time you call it, it will read another int from the input. Thus, if your input was something like

```
10
5
13
```

then the 10 would pass the `scan.nextInt()%10==0` check, and then `5` would be added to the list. Store the result of `scan.nextInt()` in a variable first, so the value won't change.

Instead of

```
if(scan.nextInt()%10==0){
liste.add(scan.nextInt());}
```

do

```
int num = scan.nextInt();
if(num%10 == 0){
    liste.add(num);
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right it pass my first value

Comment: Edited answer with code.